# Convert array wchar_t in c++ to array string in C#

Tags: c#, c++, command-line-interface, marshalling

I have two structs one in C++ and another in C#, defined as below:

In C:

```
struct A {
  wchar_t Name[24];
}
```

In C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class A {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 24*2)]
    public char[] Name;
}
```

When I use Marshal.PtrToStructure to convert the struct from C++ to C#, I get garbage characters in the string. What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is microsoft's documentation on [marshalling strings of different types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings).
The case you are looking for, fixed size unicode, would be like

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
class A {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 24)]
    public string Name;
}
```